# Import "flask" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flask

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/process_user_input', methods=['POST'])
def process_user_input():
    # Retrieve user input from the request
    user_input = request.form.get('input')

    # Return a response
    response = {'processed_input': user_input}
    return jsonify(response)
```

Comment: Is `flask` installed in your python environment? `Ctrl+Shift+P --> Python: Select Interpreter` choose the correct python interpreter.  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

The python environment you are currently using does not have the **flask** package. Use the following command to install **flask**.

```
pip install flask
```

Or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python: Select Interpreter` choose an interpreter environment with the **flask** package installed.

[image]

*[More information here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask).*